# When will 13.04 make it to "Released" status in MAAS?

Tags: server, 13.04, maas

I wanted to see if anyone knew when raring will make it to http://maas.ubuntu.com/images/ephemeral/releases/ to be downloaded and deployed by MAAS? I know the daily builds are available there, but have some issues deploying from daily builds as it is.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you confirm that you're specifically looking for Raring *ephemeral* images? These are used during enlistment and commissioning only, not for deployment. If so, could you please explain why you need Raring ephemeral images so that we can understand what you're after? Or are you just trying to deploy Raring using MAAS, in which case could you please amend your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The raring image for MAAS should be released next week. However note that by default, this is only used for enlistment/commissioning. If you would like to install raring, you don't really need this image. What you need to do is to add raring to the least of releases in:

```
/etc/maas/import_pxe_files
```

And then you need to run:

```
sudo maas-import-pxe-files
```

Answer (score 0):

Andres' answer is not sufficient (as in *it does not work*). Perhaps in a week it will. But as of today, it does not.

I added raring to the list and the import (sudo maas-import-pxe-files) failed because it couldn't find http://maas.ubuntu.com/images/query/raring/ephemeral/released-dl.txt.

Comment: Welcome to Ubuntu. Thank you for your contribution. Once you have enough reputation, consider adding content like the above as a comment not a separate answer.

Comment: Raring is now in both the ephemeral and query directories and should be ready to deploy with MAAS.